# Initialize a struct which contains vector

Tags: c++, struct

I'm looking for a method for initializing a complex struct which contains vector in a single row.

For example if I have this structure:

```
struct A{
  double x;
  double y;
};
struct B{
  double z;
  double W;
};
struct C{
  A a;
  B b;
};
```

I can initialize C in this way: `C c = {{0.0,0.1},{1.0,1.1}};`

But what If I have to initialize a struct like this?

```
struct A{
  double x;
  double y;
};
struct B{
  vector<double> values;
};
struct C{
  A a;
  B b;
};
```

I have to do it in a single row because I want to allow the users of my application to specify in a single field all the initial values. And of course, I would prefer a standard way to do it and not a custom one.

Thanks!

Comment: How do the users specify initial values? If it's a configuration file htat you specify the format, you can allow one liners. Then parse it into the structure in your C++ by using more than one line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can initialise `C` in a very similar way in C++ to in C:

```
C c = {{0.3, 0.01}, {{14.2, 18.1, 0.0, 3.2}}};
```

Comment: As long as your compiler supports C++11 initialisation syntax.

Comment: I don't believe this works very widely yet.  Initializing a `vector` with a list like that requires C++11

Comment: @MikeSeymour - Since the question did not specify a compiler, I assume the OP was asking the question about C++ as specified by the standard.

Comment: @Mankarse: Fair enough, but it's probably a good idea to specify that it's C++11 only; no compiler fully supports the new standard yet.

Comment: @Mankarse How to know the C++ version? Second, what if B is: `struct B{ vector<A> values;};?

Comment: @lucaghera: To know the C++ version of your compiler, consult the documentation for your compiler (for GCC and Clang, you need to pass `-std=c++0x` in order to enable C++11 features). No compiler yet fully supports the whole of the C++11. If B is `struct B{vector<A> values;};` then the initialisation still looks very similar: `C c{{1.1, 3.2}, {{{1.2, 3.4}, {4.2, 10.3}}}};`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not using C++11 (so you can't use Mankarse's suggestion), boost can help:

```
C c = { {0.1, 0.2}, {boost::assign::list_of(1.0)(2.0)(3.0)} };
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll just have to use [one of the constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) if you don't have the new C++11 initialization syntax.

```
    C c = {{1.0, 1.0}, {std::vector<double>(100)}};
```

The vector above has 100 elements. There's no way to initialize each element uniquely in a vector's construction.

You could do...

```
 double values[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
 C c = {{1.0, 1.0}, {std::vector<double>(values, values+5)}};
```

or if you always know the number of elements use a std::array which you can initialize the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
C obj = { { 0.0, 0.1f }, std::vector<double>( 2, 0.0 ) };
```

But obviously it's not ideal since all the values in your vector need to be the same.

Comment: he did only specify that it needed to be initialized, not set. haha

Answer (score 0):

The question is how to initialize B in the second example?

You cannot initialize a vector like this:

```
std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3 }; // doesn't work
```

You can do this

```
int data[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<int> v( &data[0], &data[0]+sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]));
```

(there are nicer ways to do that). That isn't a "one-liner" though.

This works and I have tested it:

```
template< typename T >
struct vector_builder
{
     mutable std::vector<T> v;
     operator std::vector<T>() const { return v; }
};

template< typename T, typename U >
vector_builder<T>& operator,(vector_builder<T>& vb, U const & u )
{
vb.v.push_back( u );
return vb;
}

struct B
{
  vector<double> v;

};

B b = { (vector_builder(),1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4) };

C c = { {1.1, 2.2 }, {(vector_builder(),1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4)} };
```

Answer (score -1):

```
struct C {
    A a;
    B b;
    C(double ta[2], vector<double> tb) {
        a = A(ta[0],ta[1]);    // or a.x = ta[0]; a.y = ta[1]
        b = tb;
    }
};
```

then you can initialize with something like

```
C c = C( {0.0, 0.1} , vector<double> bb(0.0,5) );
```